# verify schedule job expression

Tags: scheduled-apex, expressions

The scheduled job run everyday at 12 am.

```
String schExp = '0 0 0 * * ?';
```

Is it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is very good site to check the cron expression http://www.cronmaker.com/

When I checked your cron expresion here
[image]

I get the expected result. So yes it will work.

Answer (score 1):

```
String schExp = '0 0 0 1/1 * ? *';
```

Try this.